How can I convert all In Google Sheets cells from formulas to plain text?
I need some help after battling with this issue. & years ago this guy asked this and the script in the answer is wicked, I need the inverse, I need the words and not the formulas. Who can I do that? I'm providing a screenshoot of the Google Spreadsheet and the file link as well. Thanks in advanced:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTDF3t2Hky9r-ipKIHLcKhUOapDqkO4d8_I8y6Srn6F0SYJHTET527pGdtqiWVtJgbSqBqy78B1i8Hb/pubhtml
========
Old post:
How can I convert all cells from formulas to plain text so I can export them as CSV?
Asked 7 years, 2 months ago
Modified 6 years, 2 months ago
Viewed 4k times
4
I have around 12 sheets in a Google Spreadsheets document where I have a bunch of formulas. I'd like to do one of two things:
I would love to just export these as CSVs. I don't want the values though, I want the actual formulas. I.e. instead of the cell value being 3, I would like it to be =B2+B4. I don't mind manually downloading each.
If that's not possible, is there some way to convert all the the formula cells to the formula itself?
I know that I can just put quotes around the formulas and they will become text strings which I can then export to CSV. The issue is, that's a lot of cells ... and I don't want to have to do that for all the cells.
Can you folks help me out with this?
google-sheetsgoogle-apps-script
Share
Edit
Follow
edited Aug 20, 2017 at 17:37
pnuts's user avatar
pnuts
17.4k55 gold badges5252 silver badges103103 bronze badges
asked Aug 6, 2016 at 15:57
Ringo Blancke's user avatar
Ringo Blancke
32311 gold badge33 silver badges55 bronze badges
Add a comment
1 Answer
Sorted by:
Highest score (default)
2
The following script implements your second approach: convert all formula cells to the text displaying the formula. It does so in all sheets in the current spreadsheet.
The idea is simple: get all values (getValues) and formulas (getFormulas). If a cell contains a formula, then the new value is the formula text prepended by the apostrophe ' (which isn't displayed; it's just an indicator that the cell content should be treated as plain text).
After exporting the sheets as CSV (one by one, using the menu), you can restore the original state of the spreadsheet either by using revision history, or by running the same script again. (If the script runs again, a cell having text content =A1+1 will again become a formula =A1+1)
function formulasAsText() {
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
for (var k = 0; k < sheets.length; k++) {
var range = sheets[k].getDataRange();
var values = range.getValues();
var formulas = range.getFormulas();
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
for (var j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++) {
values[i][j] = formulas[i][j] ? "'" + formulas[i][j] : values[i][j];
}
}
range.setValues(values);
}
}
Share
Edit
Follow
answered Aug 6, 2016 at 18:56
user79865
Thanks so much for this! Works great. Accepting this answer now. I have a follow up question. Turns out that some of the cells are actually not formulas ... but just links. I have no idea how to turn a link into a hyperlink formula. Here's the question if you happen to have a few minutes / know what to do. Thanks again! webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97285/… –
Ringo Blancke
Aug 6, 2016 at 19:24

[Edit] your question to include an example of your data before and another of your data after.  Explain clearly what you want.  It isn't appropriate for users to search through the other posts to figure out what the opposite would be rather than clearly explaining what you want.

I am reviewing deleted closed questions.  Since I was the one who closed this I'm adding it to the review queue to allow the community a chance to do its own review to decide if it should remain closed or be reopened.
